# sympy 0.7.1 plot does not work

Tags: python, plot, sympy

how can i fix this, or find the logs to investigate it?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> from sympy.plotting import plot
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> p1 = plot(x*x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.1.rc1'
```

it looks like the plotting module has not been fully installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this seems to be a very old version of sympy. the api has changed. in sympy 0.7.1.rc1, `plot` is a module, not a function.](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9277)

i solved the issue by removing the existing versions of `mpmath` and `sympy` (which had been installed with `apt`) and installing the latest versions like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge python-mpmath python-sympy
$ sudo python -m easy_install mpmath
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.__version__
'0.19'
$ sudo python -m easy_install sympy
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.6'
```

now `plot()` shows the graph.

in future, use `python -m easy_install` to install the latest version, and not `apt-get` which has old versions it seems.